# How to get a program to identify a square from an array of coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qpainter

I am trying to create a program where the user can click inside the squares on a grid and create squares using PyQt5 (QPainter), but I'm having trouble getting the program to recognize when and where to draw lines. All clicked points are stored in a list.

```
clicked0 = [] #clicked points
distlist0 = [] # list of distances between 2 points
distdict0 {} = # dictionary to identify which two points go with each distance
#there are versions of these for both player 0 and player 1
```

This is the code I used to try to get the program to recognize and draw squares:

```
    for i in list(itertools.combinations(clicked0, 2)):
        woo = list(chain.from_iterable(i))
        dist = math.hypot(woo[2]-woo[0],woo[3]-woo[1])
        distlist0.append(dist)
        distdict0[str(dist)] = "("+str(woo[0])+","+str(woo[1])+"), ("+str(woo[2])+","+str(woo[3])+")"
    listy = list(itertools.combinations(distlist0, 4))
    for i in listy:
        if i[0] == i[1] and i[0] == i[2] and i[0] == i[3]:
            for item in i:
                diction = list(chain.from_iterable(distdict0.get(str(item))))
                diction = [int(diction[1]),int(diction[3]),int(diction[8]),int(diction[10])]
                x,y = self.cell2coord(diction[0],diction[1]) #method to turn grid coords into x,y coords
                x2,y2 = self.cell2coord(diction[2],diction[3])
                qp.setPen(QPen(QColor(40, 85, 66), 5))
                qp.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2)
```

This causes Python to eventually slow and crash, but here is the visual result:

[image: screenshot]

The lines are supposed to connect the colored grid spaces (the corners) when squares can be created from them. I've been working on this part of my code for hours and I'm just not sure what I can do to simplify/correct the process.

Comment: Do you mean that any two squares on the same line should be connected, or only squares in pairs of four that make a rectangle?

Comment: @Nathan Only colored grid squares in pairs of four.

Comment: why 2 users ask the same question? [Given a list of coordinates, check whether any form a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121674/python-given-a-list-of-coordinates-check-whether-any-form-a-square)

Comment: If you're the same person as the one in the other question. I would suggest closing either one of your question or merging them. It will help future readers.

Comment: Next time, when posting code. please be sure to post code that we can run without adding anything (see [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  In answers below, the posts are complete programs, omitting the graphic I/O and other unnecessary details.

Comment: Hey you should just do the project instead of asking other ppl to do it for you. #tribesquaresnotbribesquares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to loop over all coordinates and check if they form a square, for instance like this:

**Please note: this function only works for rectangles orthogonal to the original axes, for tilted rectangles, see below**

```
def rectangle(a, b, c, d):
        #sort points so they can easily be compared
        points = sorted([a, b, c, d])
        #check if corners line up
        if points[0][0] == points[1][0] and\
           points[0][1] == points[2][1] and\
           points[2][0] == points[3][0] and\
           points[1][1] == points[3][1]:
                   return True
        return False

#example data
lst_points = [[1,1],
              [1,2],
              [2,2],
              [2,1],
              [3,2],
              [4,5],
              [6,7],
              [4,2],
              [2,5]]

#loop over all sets of 4 points
for i in range(len(lst_points)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(lst_points)):
                for k in range(j+1, len(lst_points)):
                        for l in range(k+1, len(lst_points)):
                              #check if rectangle   
                              if rectangle(lst_points[i],
                                             lst_points[j],
                                             lst_points[k],
                                             lst_points[l]):
                                        print lst_points[i], lst_points[j], lst_points[k], lst_points[l]
```

This outputs

```
[1, 1] [1, 2] [2, 2] [2, 1]
[2, 2] [4, 5] [4, 2] [2, 5]
```

The only two squares in the example list

It should be relatively easy to draw the lines using this data.

This function also checks for rectangles under an angle.

```
import numpy as np

def rectangleII(a,b,c,d):
        points = sorted([a,b,c,d])
        V1 = np.array(points[1]) - np.array(points[0])
        V2 = np.array(points[2]) - np.array(points[0])
        V3 = np.array(points[3]) - np.array(points[2])
        V4 = np.array(points[3]) - np.array(points[1])
        if np.all(V1 == V3) and np.all(V2 == V4):
                if np.dot(V1, V2) == 0:
                        return True
        return False
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be the very slow way!  O(N^4).  Give it a little thought and you'll see you can omit the inner two loops (or actually, dramatically reduce them to a total of at most 4 tests).  Given a segment, how many locations do you have to test to find whether it's part of a square?

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your check routine, because it finds only the smaller  of two squares for `[ (0,0), (0,2), (0,4), (2,0), (2,2), (2,6), (4,4) ]`.  Those are the green points in the picture above.

Comment: @JeffLearman I figured OP only meant rectangles orthogonal to the original axis system. I interpreted "The lines are supposed to connect the colored grid spaces (the corners) when squares can be created from them." as such.

Comment: @JeffLearman added a function that also takes tilted squares into account

Comment: @JeffLearman I came back to this post today because someone upvoted it. I now see what you meant at the time. Thanks for trying to steer me in the right direction (although I think it flew straight over my head at the time lol)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with all points in a list, take the first point and remove it from the list. From this, iteratively pick each next point in the list and take that to be the endpoint of a segment starting at the first point. For each segment, there will be two other squares to check to see if this segment is part of a possible square. If it is, continue to check the other two corners (whose two possible locations are now fixed.) In either case, proceed with the next point to make a segment to test, until all segments starting with the first popped point have been tested.

Repeat the above (popping the next point and checking all its segments) until the list has less than 4 points.

This is O(N^2). To check if a square is filled, you could use a square array, but the solution scales better to bigger grids better if you use a dict whose key is the (x,y) coordinates (contents could be the color.)

Using combinations would generate a lot more cases. With 100 points, it's 3921225 combinations. With the above algorithm, it's n(n-1)/2 = 4950.

I suspect I'm solving someone's homework problem, but in the interest of learning, here's the code to find the set of squares, where a square is a set of four points.

```
#/usr/bin/python3

points = [ (0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4), (2, 0), (2, 2), (2, 6), (4, 4) ]

grid = {}
for point in points:
    grid[point] = 1

squares = set()     # set of frozenset(p1, p2, p3, p4), each defining a square
while len(points) >= 4:
    p1 = points.pop()
    for p2 in points:
        dx = p2[0] - p1[0]
        dy = p2[1] - p1[1]
        for delta in [(dy, -dx), (-dy, dx)]:
            p3 = (p2[0] + delta[0], p2[1] + delta[1])
            if grid.get(p3, False):
                p4 = (p3[0] - dx, p3[1] - dy)
                if grid.get(p4, False):
                    square = frozenset((p1, p2, p3, p4))    # frozen so it can be a set element
                    squares.add(square) # might be duplicate but that's OK
                break

for square in squares:
    print(list(square))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 4), (4, 4), (2, 6), (2, 2)]
[(2, 0), (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: BTW, the "pythonic" way to build `grid` above would be `grid = {p:1 for p in points}` but I didn't want to add confusion.